# Simple Knockout Viewmodel Issue

Tags: knockout.js

I have a simple knockout viewmodel problem, which is driving me round in circles... the siteId property binds the first time, but doesn't update on click:

Anyone see what's wrong with this?

```
function NewSiteAccessViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.siteId = ko.observable();
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    var newSiteAccessViewModel = new NewSiteAccessViewModel();


    newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId = 'none yet';

    ko.applyBindings(newSiteAccessViewModel);

    $(".testClick").click(function() {
        newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId = "a new one";
        alert(newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId);
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<h3 data-bind="text:siteId" ></h3>
```

So the result I get changes the value to "none yet", but doesn't subsequently update on click.  The alert shows the new value...

Comment: You need to make `siteId` an observable. There must be a dupe for this, let me try and find one.

Comment: Sorry, had tried this.. see updated code

Comment: You also need to update observables by invoking them and passing them the new value, not assigning them directly: `newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId("a new one")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You set the value of an observable by invoking the observable function. So where you wrote:

```
newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId = 'none yet';
```

you want

```
newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId('none yet');
```

and similarly from within the click handler.

Answer (score 2):

For Knockout's view model bindings to update, you must do two things:

1. The field in the view model must be created using `ko.observable()`.
2. The field must be set or updated by calling it instead of setting it directly.

So in this case:

1. `siteId` must be created in the view model as `this.siteId = ko.observable();`
2. `siteId` must be initialized as `newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId('none yet');`
3. `siteId` must be updated as `newSiteAccessViewModel.siteId('a new one');`